# Unable to map ManyToOne relashionship

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have Book User and Basket class.

1 user can have one or more book in basket table.

I want to map that relation but i keep getting the following error:

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.WalkingException: Association has already been visited: AssociationKey(table=basket,
columns={book_id})

Basket Class

```
@Entity
public class Basket {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="book_id")
private Book book;
private long user_id;


public Basket() {}
public Basket(Book book, long user_id) {
    this.book = book;
    this.user_id = user_id;
}


// Getters and Setters
}
```

Book Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Book implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@Column(name = "isbn")
private String isbn;

@Column(name = "quantity")
private Integer quantity;

@Column(name = "price")
private Double price;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONE)
@JsonIgnoreProperties("book")
private Set<SaleDetails> saleDetails = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@JoinTable(name = "book_author",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "books_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authors_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@JsonIgnoreProperties("books")
private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@JoinTable(name = "book_genre",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "books_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genres_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: Basket domain can not have List<book> it makes no sense. I only need that fot each basket object, instead of id i need the object it self...

Comment: So a Basket can only contain 1 Book, so your description is wrong. Doesn't fix the problem mind, that is utterly Hibernate specific

Comment: Sorry if i miss explain the problem. I have 3 tables User Book and Basket(id, user_id, book_id) and i'm able to get a list of baskets. But if instead of having private long book_id i try to map to and object i get the error

Comment: If you have some `User` class perhaps actually post it in the question. Otherwise if it is not related to the problem then don't even mention it ... keep the question concise